# Move one controller's path under root namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I copied the following pages in `welcome` controller

```
views/welcome/about.haml
views/welcome/brand.haml
views/welcome/brand_detail.haml
views/welcome/contact.haml
views/welcome/download.haml
views/welcome/faq.haml
views/welcome/news.haml
views/welcome/news_detail.haml
views/welcome/product.haml
views/welcome/product_detail.haml
```

Now I write my route in this way

```
  get 'welcome/index'
  get 'welcome/about'
```

It seems repeat the `welcome` many times and the namespace is not under root.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want the following in your `config/routes.rb`:

```
get 'about', to: 'welcome#about'
get 'brand', to: 'welcome#brand'

... and so on ...

root 'welcome#index'
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your **routes.rb** file

```
root 'welcome#index'
```